# Add/Modify rel=canonical of all the pages of a wordpress website

Tags: php, functions

Some background to the situation:
We're currently running two exact wordpress websites at two different domains, [xfilpak.com](https://xfilpak.com) and [xfilpak.ca](https://xfilpak.ca).  We want to make [xfilpak.ca](https://xfilpak.ca) the **canonical** website. Therefore, for a page like:
https://xfilpak.com/vertical-form-fill-seal/
there should be a code snippet like this in the `<head>` tag:
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://xfilpak.ca/vertical-form-fill-seal/" />`

We need to add the above code snippet for all the pages at [xfilpak.com](https://xfilpak.com).
Yoast SEO plugin is installed on [xfilpak.com](https://xfilpak.com) and allows us to set a **canonical URL** for each page.
But I want to do this automatically.

Comment: note that WP will auto-redirect to the canonical version of a site if you do this internally, it sounds like what you need is one install that serves the same pages on both domains. It may be possible to write a filter to swap out `xfilpak.com` with `xfilpak.ca` or the reverse, but that would be a Yoast SEO filter, not a WordPress filter, which isn't something you can ask for help with on this stack ( Yoast SEO questions are offtopic here )

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to prevent SEO plugins from adding a canonical meta tag, and then add your own canonical meta tag using `wp_head` filter (untested):

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', static function () {
    $url = trailingslashit( get_site_url() );
    $url .= ltrim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/' );

    printf( '<link ref="canonical" href="%s" />', esc_attr( $url ) );
} );
```